# tabBarOnPress not working bottomTabNAvigator

Tags: react-native, onpress

I have three screens in may BottomTabNavigator. I want to pass React native Date Picker for ios/android component as soon as third screen (Range) in bottom navigator is pressed. I tried using tabBarOnPress in my third screen in static navigationOptions, but it does not seems to work.

HEre is the snippets for my codes:

**App.js**

```
    (all imports considered)
    .......////
    const RangeStack = createStackNavigator({
      Range: {
        screen : Range
      }
    })



    export const BottomTabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
      Daily: {
        screen: DailyStack
      },
      Monthly: {
        screen: MonthlyStack
      },
      Range: {
        screen: RangeStack
      }
    })
...../////
```

**Range.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';


export const SalesUiRange = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Sales ui range</Text>
    </View>
  )
}


export class ClaimsUiRange extends React.Component {

  render () {    
    return (   
      <View>
      <Text>Claims ui range</Text>
    </View>
    )
  }
}




export default class Range extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {

      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
       alert('pressed')
        defaultHandler();
      }
    }
  }


  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
       valueOption: ''
    }
  }

     async getItem (item){
      const valueOption = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item);
      this.setState({
        valueOption
      })
}



  componentDidMount(){

    this.getItem('InitialOption');

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.valueOption === 'sales' ? <SalesUiRange/> : <ClaimsUiRange/>}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Please help to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not working because you are giving a `tabBarOnPress` property to the stackNavigator.

To give it to the route you need you have to change the createBottomTabNavigator to:

```
Range: {
    screen: RangeStack
    navigationOptions:{
       tabBarOnPress:({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
               //whatever you need to do
            defaultHandler()
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried here and it worked, but then I was not able to navigate to another screen from my app.js

Comment: What do you mean with not able to navigate? You have the defaultHandler and the navigation prop for that

Comment: should I be following like this? `navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Range' }));` inside tabBarOnPress  ?

Comment: Where do you need to navigate?

Comment: To screen named 'Range' (that is inside my RangeStack). The screen Range will open the react date picker as soon as the tab will be clicked.

Comment: It should automatically open it when you do the tabBarOnPress, as it's the direct child and the initialRouteName of the RangeStack

Comment: I tried passing alert('message') inside instead of navigation first. It  alerts only the first time after tab is pressed. After that on any number of reloading or screen navigations, alert does not work. similary, for navigation, it does not seems to trigger anything. Please help.    `Range : {
    screen : RangeStack,
    navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
        navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'DailyStack' }));
        defaultHandler()
      }
    })
  }`

Comment: `// Range: {
  //   screen: RangeStack,
  //   navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
  //     tabBarOnPress:({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
  //           alert(message')             //whatever you need to do
  //          defaultHandler()
  //      }
  // })`   even this only works for first time only

Comment: So when you navigate to RangeStack you want to navigate to DailyStack? Is that what you need? To navigate you should be able to just do navigation.navigate("DailyStack")

Comment: Just for example I write it as Daily stack. It is not navigating to any screen, neither console neither alert works.

Comment: I re-tested it in my project, and works every time i click on it, ca you post the updated app.js code you have in your question?

Comment: My application is quite big. I can share a small module. https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-native-urtdm

Comment: At this point, try removing the defaultHandler, and let it navigate how it wants. It's strange that the alert only triggers one time

Comment: Still no response

Comment: It worked anyhow. I removed and re-installed the node-modules.  Thanks for help.

Comment: Good to know man, i was going to recreate your navigation structure and check it out. it was really strange it only worked in my project.

Answer (score 2):

@Auticcat is right, but I should add that if you really want to leave the navigation options inside the component, it is possible to use [getActiveChildNavigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#getactivechildnavigationoptions) in your navigator.

```js
export const BottomTabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Daily: {
    screen: DailyStack,
  },
  Monthly: {
    screen: MonthlyStack,
  },
  Range: {
    screen: RangeStack,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
      ...getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation, screenProps),
    }),
  }
});
```